# Android Studio layout preview not showing when adding YoutubePlayer Component, Exception in layout

Tags: java, android, layout, youtube-api, invisible

I'm having an issue with a YoutubePlayerView, thats causing my entire layout to be invisible. When I delete it or remove it from the design, all of the remaining becomes visible. It is showing a message warning,

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.   at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>  at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>  at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2)   at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)   at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505) Copy stack to clipboard
```

**Things to consider:**

- When the app is running the Youtube Player is working fine

**What i've tried:**   (DIDN'T WORKED)

- Invalidating cache and restarting IDE
- Reinstalling Android Studio
- Creating a new fragment with only a YoutubePlayerView Component

[Android Studio Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7yOa.png)

I'll be glad if someone could help, been stuck with this for a week

Comment: That seems like a bug in the YouTube player, where it does not work properly with the Android Studio designer. Make sure you are on [the latest version of the library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads), though it looks like that has not been updated since 2016. They do have [a beta version](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/revision_history#release_notes_09_15_2022), but the download link leads to a 404. Otherwise, you may need to live without the designer for this layout.